# Setting up UserApp.io on ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, configuration, ember-cli, userapp

This may seem trivial, but I have been unsuccessful at getting this to work. I have used UserApp.io successfully for user/authentication management. I recently created an ember app using ember-cli, but I am unable to get the two to work together despite ember being supported by UserApp.io. Here are there instructions (integrating with ember without cli).

https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-ember

Here is a snippet:

Include the UserApp JavaScript library and this Ember module in your index.html. Be sure to add them before your app.js file.

```
<script src="https://app.userapp.io/js/userapp.client.js"></script>
<script src="https://app.userapp.io/js/ember-userapp.js"></script>
```

(You can also install the module with bower: `$ bower install userapp-ember`)

Initiate the module

Add this code above `App = Ember.Application.create();` in app.js with your App Id.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'userapp',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        Ember.UserApp.setup(application, { appId: 'YOUR-USERAPP-APP-ID' });
    }
});
```

Because I am using ember-cli I have created a file called `userapp.js` in an initializers folder which has the following code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
    name: 'userapp',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        Ember.UserApp.setup(application, { 
            appId: 'USERAPP-ID-INSERTED-HERE',
            loginRoute: 'login',
            indexRoute: 'index',
            heartbeatInterval: 20000,
            usernameIsEmail: false
        });
    }
};
```

When I run my app I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setup' of undefined
```

I feel like this is something simple/stupid, but for the life of me I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: It seems ember-userapp.js is not getting included in ur app. Can you confirm if it is included. If you are using bower to install it, edit the Brocfile.js to include the lib like app.import('bower_components/userapp-ember/ember-userapp.js'); Its mentioned here http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-non-amd-asset

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I figured it was something trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `ember-userapp.js` is not getting included in ur app. If you are using bower to install it, edit the `Brocfile.js` to include the lib like

`app.import('bower_components/userapp-ember/ember-userapp.js');`

Its mentioned here http://ember-cli.com/#standard-non-amd-asset